# Joomla 2.5 admin page will not show

Tags: joomla2.5

I am upgrading from Joomla 1.5 to 2.5 and developed my site in a sub folder on the live site. Everything was working fine in the test area. (dev site is here: http://academyphysicians.com/test) Used Akeba backup and moved the site to the root folder. Front end is working as expected, but the admin page is blank after log in. New install of 2.5 is here: http://academyphysicians.com.

I was googling the issue and saw that php version may be the problem. I am running v 5.2.14 and I saw that 5.3 may be required. It seem like I would have had the problem in the test site if that was the case. Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the site worked in a subfolder, then it will work in the root. When you moved the site you did something wrong or you have touched a setting you shouldn't have because Joomla should be folder agnostic.

Comment: Yup - I used kickstart to administer the Akeba backup archive and that did it.